# Parsing JSON with AJAX/jquery not displaying

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax

Doing a small assignment using an API to pull up film quotes, don't see what I am doing wrong with the code. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
<div class="col-md-6" id="quoteOutput">

    <br>
    <div id="singleQuote"></div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3" id="qwe"></div>

</div>
</body>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://viralpatel.net/blogs/demo/jquery/jquery.shorten.1.0.js"></script>

<script>
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://movie-quotes-2.herokuapp.com/api/v1/quotes/1",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $("#singleQuote").append("<div><h1>" + data.response.film + "</h1></div><br>");
                $("#singleQuote").append("<div>" + data.response.content + "</div>");
                $("#singleQuote").append("<div>" + data.response.character + "</div>");
                $("#singleQuote").append("<div>" + data.response.actor + "</div>");
                $("#singleQuote").append("<hr>");
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(data) {
console.log(data);
//for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $("#singleQuote").append("<div><h1>" + data.film + "</h1></div><br>");
    $("#singleQuote").append("<div>" + data.content + "</div>");
    $("#singleQuote").append("<div>" + data.character + "</div>");
    $("#singleQuote").append("<div>" + data.actor + "</div>");
    $("#singleQuote").append("<hr>");
//}
};
```

Comment: The object 'data' has no properties property 'response'. 
If the object 'data' will return many values - use `$.each(data, function () { ... your append's ... })`